# How to scale for national database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am currently designing a relational database to handle voting intention data for political parties. Local parties will have the ability to upload their electoral registers (CSV) and then record voter intentions for that person.

Each local party would have a number of tables - geographical (polling districts, local government, states), political parties and intention history. To scale for a national campaign, where parties would be able to track local data, do you believe this can be achieved with the addition of another table for each state, or do I require a number of databases (considering the number of people living in the country).

On a side note, the registers contain the electorate's name, address, voter eligibility etc, do you believe that the 3NF should be adhered to and that addresses should be separate?

Comment: This sounds like a relatively small database considering what mysql can handle. Yes, relational. But you choose relations for situations where a user can have many to one. And I would store extra data in another table. Just keep the user table to a minimum. Scaling would make sense when your user base grows extremely large, and at that point you might consider redundancies and syncing. Otherwise, this sounds like a pretty simple system

Comment: Adding a table for each state will only help you kill yourself later. You're not helping anyone by having a separate table per state. Having multiple tables with **same** structure makes exactly 0 sense because you're going to have, oh so much fun cross referencing the data. MySQL can handle tens of billions of records, it always depends on the hardware used (a blade with a Fusion-IO card would fly through tens of billions or records like a hot knife through butter). Keep it simple, it's a simple system with not so many records.

Comment: @N.B. I think there was some confusion. I wasn't suggesting that I create a separate table per state, but rather a separate table to hold all states. Each user would have a one to many relationship with states, but in general this would only be used by national party, with privileges for users normally being set to access one state information only.

Comment: Ah, my bad then, I apologize. Separate table to hold states makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

A few points.

When trying to scale, always start with normalized data.  You may have to denormalize as you scale up but where and when you do, you may not know in advance.  Normalization provides a number of general optimizations both in terms of data management and performance.  Once you start denormalizing you will find more maintenance issues (and data anomalies), and you will find that you have optimized for one query type or another at the expense of others (you may find you can improve some queries by a factor of 10 while other queries take a factor of 10 longer, which is usually not a win unless you know in advance it will be).  I have worked in cases where we have had to break 1NF to maintain good performance but in so doing we effectively close the door to some sorts of queries.

Secondly, one thing MySQL doesn't have (and which may force you to make clever optimizations or move to PostgreSQL) is a recursive common table expression.  This means you can't gracefully do tree structures or breadth-first-searches on graphs in SQL.  For geographic databases that can be a big issue (think of dividing up the nation into states, each state into counties, each county into precincts and then attaching staff to be responsible for all of this).  So this is one area where you will want to think over your design and look at how people do it on MySQL (or move to PostgreSQL where you can generate trees recursively in a single query).

Comment: Thank you for this information. Would you recommend any sites, videos or books that I could look at for tree structures and user/role assignment that may help me with this design?

Comment: Unfortunately scaling databases is something which takes more experience than it does knowledge.  I.e. the question of what not to optimize is as important as the question to optimize.  And often suddenly low-level details (like how stuff is stored in a table) can suddenly become important.  I wish I had good recommendations there. In reality best option is to work with people experienced in this regard or just try and ask questions when you have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Handling a national electoral register in principle shouldn't be too challenging. The world's largest democracy, India, has a roll of 850 million electors - a volume well within the capacity of any good DBMS.

There are a number of elector database software packages already in existence and used by political parties in many countries. Presumably you will want to research those before you start work on your own alternative. If you are determined to build your own solution then your question seems to indicate that you'll need some assistance. Put your questions on database design to your development team.